# What does git push do without arguments

Tags: git

Does `git push origin master` do exactly the same thing as `git push`?

Answer (score 5):

`git push` alone has been deprecated (not supported) for some time, because it is implicit, rather than explicit.

It is better practice, and not to mention much safer (will likely stop you from accidentally pushing the wrong branch to the wrong remote).

Thus, it is best to use `git push <remote> <branch>`

Comment: Okay but was it the same thing before been deprecated ?

Comment: and git pull without arguments is deprecated too ?

Comment: AFAIK, `git push` pushed the currently checked-out branch to the `origin` remote. So, if `git status` said you were in the master branch, and `git remote -v` returned the remote `origin`, then `git push` would be the same as `git push origin master`

Comment: Yes I believe `git pull` without any arguments is also deprecated.

Comment: @RThomP Can you provide a reference for deprecation? I've never heard about deprecated bare `git pull/push`, docs don't say anything and search reveals nothing.

Comment: It's not deprecated. Whether it's a good *habit* is another question entirely, but bad habit or not, I use it all the time...